# object detection and classification using yolov3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, google-colaboratory

i trained multiple fruits but the problem is that when i try to test the model, only detect single object as shown in apple image. but when i try to test for multiple fruits some time it does not detect or detect as a hole .. as shown in apple,banana image and multiple fruits.. what is the problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/888Zj.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfDTc.jpg)

Comment: how many samples do you use for training? What kind of images (perspectives, background, etc.) do you use?

Comment: i am using 5 samples (apple ,banana, orange,satrwberry,pomegranate) ... images have white backgroung.. each image contains one fruit

Comment: how many teaining sample images per class?  If you only use images wirh white background during training it is no surprise that it does not work with different background. Your training is biased.

Comment: 2500 per class ....

Comment: Please add a sample training image with annotations along with config files *(.cfg, .obj and .names)* here to understand what could have gone wrong. Current info is insufficient.